# pgfplots fill above two lines with domain

Tags: pgfplots, latex3, fillbetween

iam trying to fill above the green and the red line, between the two brown lines. Ive tried it with soft clip and domain, but i cant get it working. Here is what iam trying to achieve (thick organe lines or just this space filled).

[image]

Code so far is:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmax=5,xmin=-5,xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
      minor tick num=1,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$x_2$,label style =
      {at={(ticklabel cs:1.1)}}]
      \addplot[draw=green, name path=A]{7/2 -2*x}; 
      \addplot[draw=red, name path=B]{3/2 - x/2};
      \addplot[draw=blue, name path=C]{1- x/3};

      \addplot +[mark=none,draw=brown, name path=D] coordinates {(1,-6) (1,6)};
      \addplot +[mark=none,draw=brown, name path=E] coordinates {(2,-6) (2,6)};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use clips.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmax=5,xmin=-5,xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
      minor tick num=1,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$x_2$,label style =
      {at={(ticklabel cs:1.1)}}]
      \addplot[draw=green, name path=A,samples=2]{7/2 -2*x} 
        coordinate[pos=0] (A0) coordinate[pos=1] (A1); 
      \addplot[draw=red, name path=B,samples=2]{3/2 - x/2}
        coordinate[pos=0] (B0) coordinate[pos=1] (B1);
      \addplot[draw=blue, name path=C,samples=2]{1- x/3}
        coordinate[pos=0] (C0) coordinate[pos=1] (C1);
      \path (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
        coordinate (TL)  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
        coordinate (TR);    
      \begin{scope}
       \clip (TL) -- (A0) -- (A1) -- (TR) -- cycle;
       \clip (TL) -- (B0) -- (B1) -- (TR) -- cycle;
       \clip (TL) -- (C0) -- (C1) -- (TR) -- cycle;
       \path[pattern={Lines[angle=45]},pattern color=red] (1,-6) rectangle (2,6);
      \end{scope} 
      \addplot +[mark=none,draw=brown, name path=D] coordinates {(1,-6) (1,6)};
      \addplot +[mark=none,draw=brown, name path=E] coordinates {(2,-6) (2,6)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that obviously did it! Have to do a lot more of this type of graph, so clips will be properly very handy ^^