# shadow in picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

Can you help me with this function?

Comment: Have you an exam of LaTeX?

Comment: Please show what you've tried. E.g., an example showing you can already draw the function, but not the shadow.

Comment: please help me with tikz

Comment: What is the problem? How to draw a function or how to insert shadow between some function and left side of diagram?

Comment: You asked 10 questions, non of them has an accepted answer. Most most of them show just an image and not a single line of code, i.e. "just do this graphic for me" questions. These are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573863/95441, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385738/95441.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear, what is your problem: fill area where `y>f(x)` or definition of the function `f(x)` (the later is actually math problem).

In any case it is simpler to use `pgfplots` package (which is based on `tikz` package) than pure `tikz` package, where you need to draw axis, labels, etc. yourself.

Let me focused on shading. Using `pgfplots` package it can be done by use of `fill between` function defined in the `pgfplotslibrary` library:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
declare function = {f(\x) = 3*(\x-1)+3;}, % here you define own function, 
                                          % for example  f(\x) = (\x-1)^3+1;, etc
    axis lines=center,
    xtick=\empty,   ytick=\empty,
    axis on top,
%
    label style={anchor=north east},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
%
    domain=-3:3,  samples=101, no marks,
    xmin=-2, xmax=3,
    ymin=-3, ymax=3,
%
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1pt},
                ]
  \addplot +[name path=F]    {f(x)};
  \path     [name path=Y]
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) 
            node[text=blue, below right=3mm] {$y\geq f(x)$};
  \addplot [fill=blue!10] fill between [of = F and Y]; % end of fillbetween
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that in above MWE you consider for function @Sebastiano suggestion, i.e. `f(\x) = (\x-1)^3 +1` and change definition and observation domain to:

```
    domain=-2:3,  samples=101, no marks,
    xmin=-2, xmax=4,
    ymin=-2, ymax=3,
```

the obtained image is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For fun, I propose this easy  short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{sansmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-3 ,-3)(3.5,3.2)
\sansmath
\psset{algebraic, plotpoints=500, labelsep=2pt}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Lavender, linestyle=none]%
{\psline(-3,-3)(-1.442,-3)\psplot{-1.442}{1.442}{x^3} \psline(1.442,3)(-3,3)(-3,-3)}
\psplot[linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=RoyalBlue,]{-1.442}{1.442}{x^3} 
\psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, showorigin=false, arrows=->,arrowinset=0.12, linecolor=black] %
(-1,-1)(-3,-3)(3.2,3)[$x$, 0][$y$,180]
\rput(0,2.5){$\color{RoyalBlue}y\ge f(x)$}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, you have not used Geogebra....ahahah :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano: No, I just used a calculator to have an approximation of the cubic root of $3$ and cheated a bit with the axes.

Comment: If you see my humble answer the function seem to be (x-1)^{3}+1. I have used Desmos .

Comment: I quite agree, but I thought it was simpler to plot the standard x^3, and have axes intersecting at (–1,–1).

Answer (score 1):

My idea it is simple if you have a lot of difficulty to plot in TikZ: plot the function `(x-1)^{3}+1` using Geogebra and you can define a shadow zone with a inequality. With Geogebra you can put all the labels in sans-serif font and export in *TikZ*, eventually making some corrections. At the end changed the tips with the classic arrow of `tikz-cd`.

Comment: I have errors: Undefined control sequence. ...{$ x^{3} $} \psline(1.442,3)(-3,3)(-3,-3)}    Undefined control sequence. ...linecolor=blue,]{-1.442}{1.442}{$ x^{3} $}    Undefined control sequence. ...linecolor=blue,]{-1.442}{1.442}{$ x^{3} $}

Comment: @Juliperezor, please edit your question and add the code what you try so far!

Comment: @Zarko Hi, I have not understood the comment of the OP. :-) I see a lot of confusion.

Comment: @Sebastiano, me either. As you can see from my comments and answer, I didn't figured out, what actually is OP's problem.